# Change the name Attribute of product to not required magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, required

**I want to generate the name of product based by sku.**

For example : when i enter `10014000` for the sku, the name of product will be `Bovin phenelop 16/18 blanc 100`. 
This information is coming from segmenting the sku and doing some request to some tables to recuperate this name, but i can't find any phtml file for adding product, so i used the event and observer.

But, the problem is, i still need to fill the product name input because it's required field, so how to make the product name to not required and is it safe to do that? Or instead, is there a best solution to use ajax? And when creating a product, if i enter sku, the name will be generated in same time before saving the product?

Please help me find a way to put some ajax and which file is a form to adding new product?

Comment: can you please rephrase? it's quite hard to understand what you want to do

Comment: ok and thanks for your replay

Comment: did you change the product name with observer before?

Comment: yes but i should always put some name and not leave the name empty and it's not a sol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This can be possible by backend

You can change require option value from the attributes.
Go to **Store->attributes->product** search **code "name"** and set **Values Required to NO**

Comment: so there is no way to use ajax and is'it safe to change the name of product to not required

Comment: Yes it is safe.

Comment: thanks for your replay :)

Comment: Yes , Thank you.. It's Working..